# Is passing Object type as a method parameter always a sign of poor design?

Tags: java, oop

Assume I have the following enum

```
public enum EmailType {
    FORGET_PASSWORD, ACHIEVMENT_UNLOCK, WELCOME
}
```

and I have a function that generates email subjects based on the type (but it still requires dynamic data), e.g.

```
public String generateEmailSubject(EmailType emailType, Object obj) {
    String subject;
    switch(emailType) {
        case WELCOME:
            User user = (User) obj;
            subject = "Hello " + user.getFirstName();
        case FORGET_PASSWORD:
            User user = (User) obj;
            subject = "Forget password " + user.getEmail();
            break;
        case ACHIEVMENT_UNLOCK:
            Achievment achievment = (Achievment) obj;
            subject = "Achievment Unlock:" + achievment.getTitle();
            break;
    }

    return subject;
}
```

Is this bad practice? If so, what's a good design to handle this? Maybe a separate method for each `EmailType` but that could lead to a lot of methods and the subjects will not be centralized when I need to change them.

Comment: Normally you'd have your different possible types of object implement some interface with (for instance) a `getSubject()` method.

Comment: You do not really need the type. You could use `if(obj instanceof User)`

Comment: @c0der It's true I don't need the type in the example above but actually I'll need it under some circumstances, where for example there are 2 cases where I send an object of type `User` and the 2 cases should yield different subjects.

Comment: You will violate Open Closed principle if you would want to introduce new subject for a new EmailType. It would be good to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use polymorphism for this.

```
interface Subjectable {
    String getSubject();
}

class Achievement implements Subjectable {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getSubject() {
        return "Achievement unlocked: " + getTitle();
    }
}

class User implements Subjectable {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getSubject() {
        return "Forgot password: " + getEmail();
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to explicitly check the type of the object: you just call `getSubject()` on it.

Comment: Thanks, but bear with me here. What if `Achievment` or `User` can return different subjects under different circumstances? I suppose I'll let `getSubject` take an `EmailType` and do the logic inside implementing class based on the type, am I correct? But that leads me to ask another question, `EmailType` enum have many values (ones that are not related to `User` or `Achievment`) so is it fine if I only create cases for the related types only? However if someone calls getSubject with a unrelated type `getSubject()` will return null.

Comment: I added another case to my post above to elaborate

Comment: It sounds like you're not "passing object type as a parameter" at all, since the enum you are passing indicates more than just the other object's type. In that case, [ernest_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53087714/3890632).

Comment: I didn't mean object type as in `User.class`, I meant raw `Object`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to khelwood's solution (in case, for example, you can't change the structure of `User` and `Achievement`), it may make sense to consider that the subject extraction operation really belongs with `EmailType`. If `EmailType` has the `generateEmailSubject` method, that would make a more cohesive unit instead of having the logic spread between it and whatever class currently defines `generateEmailSubject()`.

```
public enum EmailType {

    FORGET_PASSWORD {
        @Override
        public String generateEmailSubject(Object obj) {
            User user = (User) obj;
            return "Forget password " + user.getEmail();
        }
    },

    ACHIEVMENT_UNLOCK {
        @Override
        public String generateEmailSubject(Object obj) {
            Achievment achievment = (Achievment) obj;
            return "Achievment Unlock:" + achievment.getTitle();
        }
    };

    public abstract String generateEmailSubject(Object obj);
}
```

Comment: I feel that your answer fits my situation more, not because I can't edit existing classes but because if I go with an interface I'll still have to pass `EmailType` to the `generateSubject(EmailType emailType)` because a `User` can have different subjects for different types of emails (see my edit above, `WELCOME` and `FORGET_PASSWORD`). But is `(Object obj)` then casting to object poor design? Or is it ok? Thanks

Comment: @prettyvoid Casting from `Object` should only be used if necessary. Whenever you can, use a more specific supertype for `User` and `Achivement` because that makes a more type-safe and precise API.

Comment: Can you explain, if only briefly, how a supertype would be a better solution? The way I imagine it going with a supertype, would be a bit similar to khelwoods solution above.. where I still have to pass `EmailType` to `generateSubject()` method because a `User` could generate multiple subjects depending on the `emailType`. And I think this is a bit bad because `EmailType` have many values, I don't want someone to call `user.generateSubject(emailType)` with in-appropriate type. Unless I start splitting my `EmailType` for example `UserEmailType`&`AchievmentEmailType`.Thoughts?Thanks for bearing

Comment: With khelwood's solution, you don't need to specify `EmailType` to get the correct subject. As long as your API uses something to the effect of `Subjectable`, it allows for that polymorphic flexibility and subject extraction has only only the `getSubject()` method to call. Now about why a common supertype is better (than `Object`): it's simply cleaner API and better type safety (general guideline, though). Now I'm not saying that having `EmailType.generateEmailSubject` is worse than using an interface (I prefer that on the contrary), I just thought the interface was your natural next step.

Comment: But as I explained a `User` object could yield more than one subject depending on the `EmailType`, that means even with the interface solution I still have to supply `emailType` to `getSubject()`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ahh... I didn't know that... In that case, the subject has more to do with `EmailType` than with anything else. Then I believe my solution will work best as it's coupled with the right thing, `emailType`.